# Display total unique custon field results

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I need show total results of a custom_field:

- Each post has a field "city";
- How many unique cities are registered?

Ex.:
Madrid + Paris + Madrid + London = 3 cities

Comment: The question is not WordPress specific, rather PHP specific, and is an off-topic here. You can search how to count strings in PHP. :)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam - I think you have misunderstood the question

Comment: it's ok. Got it now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a SQL query via the [wpdb class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb):

```
$query =    "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT meta_value )
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE meta_key = 'city'";       
$unique_cities = $wpdb->get_var( $query );
echo 'Total number of cities: ' . $unique_cities;
```

Comment: Yeps! This worked well for cities, thanks!

How is the code for the case of countries? In countries there is a select field with all available options. Need to count just how many countries have post.

Comment: how are countries stored? I'm guessing it would work the same way.